# No Way to Ingest Data With \" in a Field Into BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have tens of thousands of compressed CSV files that are written to S3 every day. They contain comma separated fields, each field is enclosed in double quotes (regardless of data type). However, double quotes contained within a field are escaped with a `\` instead of the [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) standard `"` like so:

```
header1,header1,header3
"1","Look some text.","43.7"
"2","27\" TV","29.1"
"3","More things","99.0"
```

This works fine for Amazon Athena, or other products that use deserializers that let you specify the quote/escape character. However, BigQuery cannot ingest this data. I receive the error:

`Error: Data between close double quote (\") and field separator.`

When I try, which makes sense. I cannot change the underlying data structure (written by another service), setting the `configuration.load.quote` param to an unused character gives me parsing errors, and it's not feasible to spin up Cloud SQL instances to just act as a parser for this (I'm processing TBs of data every day).

I thought setting the quote char to `\"` might work but the BQ API only allows a single character for that field.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the pain, and thanks for providing the additional motivation!

As I explained on my post (https://medium.com/google-cloud/loading-mysql-backup-files-into-bigquery-straight-from-cloud-sql-d40a98281229), the easiest way I found to deal with this issue for now is to go through MySQL.

Other questions on Stack Overflow show alternative paths, like pre-processing with Dataflow, bash tools, and/or inside BigQuery.

For product feature developments, please subscribe and upvote this issue - adding your comments there will also be very valuable:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906027

To parse inside BigQuery, try loading each row raw and running a UDF like this:

```
SELECT csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] a
  , csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] b
  ,csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] c
  ,csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] d
  ,csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] e
  ,csv.cols[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] f
FROM (
  SELECT fhoffa.x.parse_csv('hello,"dealing here, with", some \" quoted words, all is fine, good one?,"even a , in between"')  csv
)
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83

[image]